# Executing a Java jar file from within a SoapUI groovy script not working

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to SoapUI and Groovy so please forgive this post as it has been posted a number of times in Stackoverflow however I cannot find a fix.

SoapUI version:  4.5.2

I have 2 questions if you guys don't mind:

1. I have an executable jar file that I've put in the the \bin\ext directory along with another jar that is considered a dependency jar within the code in the jar so I hope it will reference there. The groovy code I found in Stackoverflow that should execute this jar is as follows but does not work as I don't see any output anywhere in the SoapUI directory.

Here is the code:

```
def command = "java -jar UpdateAppIdXMLRequest.jar file.xml"
def process = command.execute()
process.waitFor()

def output = process.in.text
log.info output
```

1. This jar creates 25 xml files that should be able to be picked up by the SoapUI and put them in as TestSteps in the same project. In my java code in what path do I put these files?

Here is the code in my jar:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

class UpdateAppIdXMLRequest {

    static main(args) {

        try {

          SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
          File xmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");

          Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
          Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

          // Create loop to create 25 testStepApps
          for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {

              // Get current AppID, incrementAppID and update the ApplicationNumber attribute value for next test script.
              int appID = Integer.parseInt(rootNode.getAttributeValue("ApplicationNumber"));
              appID++;
              String appIDValue = Integer.toString(appID);
              rootNode.getAttribute("ApplicationNumber").setValue(appIDValue);

              XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

              // Create new XML file with next AppID
              xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
              xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("c:\\testStepApp" + i + ".xml"));

              // xmlOutput.output(doc, System.out);

              // System.out.println("File updated!");
          }
        } catch (IOException io) {
          io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what your jar is doing, so when you execute the groovy test step what do you see in the `Log Output` tab of this test step as you are printing `log.info output`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I stated, I don't know much about groovy however, I'm reading the code whereby the log.info command is taking a parameter of "output" which is defined right above this line of code.  Is that not correct?  Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't say that the code was wrong. In order to help you I want to know the log printed by groovy script when its executed. The `log.info` prints the information in the `Log Output` tab, this tab is just behind the groovy test step window inside the SOAPUI. Other possibility that someone can help you is that you share the `.jar` code.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In the SOAPUI Log Output here is what I got:

Tue Sep 02 06:55:22 CDT 2014:INFO:

I included my the code in my jar in my original post above.  Again thanks for any help you can provide.  Regards.

Comment: Hi @Melinda you can do all this things directly with groovy test step and it's not necessary to use a .jar (you can avoid include the jar code in the /bin/ext lib, recompile the code if you make some changes etc...). I'll prepare and explanation an post it as answer in a fer minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do so, I recommend that you use directly groovy test step instead of a jar, this way you have more flexibility an you have not recompile the jar each time you must need to change something.

So, in order to achieve your goal, at first you need to create a `TestCase` inside your project, create  a `SOAP Test Step` and `Groovy Test Step` inside like this:

[image]

I will use `SOAP Test Step` to create the other test steps (to create test steps it needs the `wsdl:operation` and so on, and it's more easy to copy the test step that create directly).

In the `Groovy Test Step` I will put the necessary code to do the work which is showed below:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory

// read your request template
def requestFile = new File("C:/file.xml");
// parse it as xml
def requestXml = new XmlHolder(requestFile.text)

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase;
// get the testStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("Template");

// loop to create 25 testStep
for(int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
    // xpath expression to get applicationNumber attribute in root node
    def xpathNodeAttr = "/*/@ApplicationNumber";

    // get the root node attribute applicationNumber throught an XPATH
    int appId = Integer.parseInt(requestXml.getNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr));
    // add 1 to appId
    appId++;
    // set the value again in the attribute
    requestXml.setNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr,appId);


    def testStepName = "TestStep_ApplicationNumber_"+ String.valueOf(appId)
    log.info testStepName;
    log.info testStepName.getClass().getName()
    log.info tc.getClass().getName()
    // create a new testStepConfig
    def testStepFactory = new WsdlTestRequestStepFactory();
    def testStepConfig = testStepFactory.createConfig( tsTemplate.getOperation(), testStepName )
    // add the new testStep to TestCase
    def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 )
    // set the request which just create
    newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(requestXml.getXml())
}
```

This code it's basically your `java` code "translated" to `groovy` and added the necessary code to create the test steps. In a few words this code reads a request from a file, and create 25 test steps in the current test case using the request, in each request it only changes the `ApplicationNumber` attribute of the root node adding it +1.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

If you use a `REST Request step` instead of `SOAP Request Step` you have to change a bit your groovy code to use `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory` and `getTestRequest()` method on it. So if you have a REST Service with a POST method create a `Test Case` with a `REST Request test step` and `Groovy Test Step` like this:

[image]

And use this groovy code instead, basically this code it's the same and works like the code above and makes the same thing with `REST Request` instead of `SOAP Request`:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory

// read your request template
def requestFile = new File("C:/file.xml");
// parse it as xml
def requestXml = new XmlHolder(requestFile.text)

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase;
// get the testStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("Template");

// loop to create 25 testStep
for(int i = 1; i < 26; i++){
    // xpath expression to get applicationNumber attribute in root node
    def xpathNodeAttr = "/*/@ApplicationNumber";

    // get the root node attribute applicationNumber throught an XPATH
    int appId = Integer.parseInt(requestXml.getNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr));
    // add 1 to appId
    appId++;
    // set the value again in the attribute
    requestXml.setNodeValue(xpathNodeAttr,appId);


    def testStepName = "TestStep_ApplicationNumber_"+ String.valueOf(appId)
    log.info testStepName;
    log.info testStepName.getClass().getName()
    log.info tc.getClass().getName()
    // create a new testStepConfig
    def testStepFactory = new RestRequestStepFactory();
    def testStepConfig = testStepFactory.createConfig( tsTemplate.getTestRequest(), testStepName )
    // add the new testStep to TestCase
    def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 )
    // set the request which just create
    newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(requestXml.getXml())
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG!  Thank you so much.  I appreciate your help and more importantly your time.  I'll give it a try and hopefully this will help our QA person who works in SoapUI.  I was trying to write out some code in Java to help him since he's not a developer.  Thanks again.

Comment: Problem running REST app. Here is ERROR:An error occured [No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory.createConfig() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestResource, java.lang.String) values: [com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestResource@ad74f1, TestStep_ApplicationNumber_65244040]
Possible solutions: createConfig(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation, java.lang.String), createConfig(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest, java.lang.String)], see error log for details

Comment: I thought that you were using SOAP Test Request because you deal with an xml requests, however you are using a REST resource so you need a different way to create the test steps because my code is to create SOAP Test request. I update the answer to add groovy code which works with REST Request instead of SOAP Request, take a look on it. I hope this time achieve your goal `:)`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wish SoapUI had intellisense to help new users find other methods to use.  I sure appreciate all your time and help.  It is appreciated.  Have a great weekend.

Comment: Yeah a intellisense in groovy script in SOAPUI will be great!, try it and give me a feedback. Have a nice weekend too.